# Neo4j: slow aggregation with large number of nodes

Tags: neo4j

I am new to Neo4j. At the moment I am evaluating the use of Neo4j for one of our use cases. I run into problems when I am trying to aggregate with a large number of nodes.

We are using Neo4j to store visitors who cast votes relating to different categories. A vote has a location and a referrer which I modelled as individual nodes in order to 'reuse' them.
This is roughly what my schema looks like (Node Vote has additional relationships which  am omitting here):

```
(Visitor {id})-[VOTED]->(Vote)-[RELATES_TO]->(Category {name})
```

With an index on Vistor.id and Category.name

Our data set is quite large, so I started testing my schema with 4 million votes and 3 million visitors. The votes relate to 18 different categories.
I want to be able to do aggregations. For example I need to get the number of distinct visitors who voted for 'Category A' and 'CATEGORY B'.

```
MATCH (c:Category)<-[:PARENT*0..3]-(child:Category)<-[:RELATES_TO]-(v:Vote)<-[:VOTED]-(visitor:Visitor)
WHERE c.name = 'Category A'
WITH visitor
MATCH (c:Category)<-[:RELATES_TO]-(v:Vote)<-[:VOTED]-(visitor)
WHERE c.name = 'Category B'
RETURN count(distinct(visitor.id)) as Cat_A_and_B_lovers
```

This takes almost 30 seconds

I would also like to be able to get all categories and the number of distinct votes:

```
MATCH (n:Category)<-[:RELATES_TO]-(:Vote)<-[:VOTED]-(v:Visitor)
RETURN n.name as category, count(DISTINCT v) as count;
```

This takes 13 seconds.

Is it possible to improve these timings, or is Neo4j just not the right fit for this type of analysis?
We are also analysing data on a per visitor level - but would like to be able to do these aggregations as well.

My Setup:
Linux, 4 cores 14GB
Noe4j community version
neo4j.conf:

```
dbms.memory.heap.initial_size = 2G
dbms.memory.heap.max_size = 10G
dbms.memory.pagecache.size = 10g
```

**-- UPDATE 15/02**

Following Michael's suggestions I was able to improve the execution time of both queries. My first query:

```
PROFILE MATCH (n:Category)<-[:RELATES_TO]-()<-[:VOTED]-(v:Visitor)
WITH n, count(DISTINCT v) as count
RETURN n.name as category, count
```

PROFILE output:

9964 ms

Compiler CYPHER 3.1

Planner COST

Runtime INTERPRETED

```
+-------------------+----------------+---------+---------+--------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
| Operator          | Estimated Rows | Rows    | DB Hits | Variables                            | Other                              |
+-------------------+----------------+---------+---------+--------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
| +ProduceResults   |           1545 |      18 |       0 | category, count                      | category, count                    |
| |                 +----------------+---------+---------+--------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
| +Projection       |           1545 |      18 |      18 | category -- count, n                 | {category : n.name, count : count} |
| |                 +----------------+---------+---------+--------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
| +EagerAggregation |           1545 |      18 |       0 | count -- n                           | n                                  |
| |                 +----------------+---------+---------+--------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
| +Filter           |        2386269 | 4114784 | 4114784 | anon[19], anon[35], anon[37], n, v   | v:Visitor                          |
| |                 +----------------+---------+---------+--------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
| +Expand(All)      |        2386269 | 4114784 | 8229568 | anon[37], v -- anon[19], anon[35], n | ()<-[:VOTED]-(v)                   |
| |                 +----------------+---------+---------+--------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
| +Expand(All)      |        4113784 | 4114784 | 4114807 | anon[19], anon[35] -- n              | (n)<-[:RELATES_TO]-()              |
| |                 +----------------+---------+---------+--------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
| +NodeByLabelScan  |             23 |      23 |      24 | n                                    | :Category                          |
+-------------------+----------------+---------+---------+--------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
```

It takes almost 10 seconds now. I would need to get it below 1 second. Is this feasible at all (using neo4j)?

Comment: This might be better suited for Code Review. Stack Overflow is here to help with a actual problem, meaning "fixing something that does not work "in contrary to "improve something that does work".

Comment: What about index?

Comment: I have an index on Vistor.id and Category.name.

Answer (score 0):

Don't configure more memory than you have.

Set page cache to 4G and min/max-heap to 8

for the query it would be good to look at the query plan with `EXPLAIN` and `PROFILE`.

I recommend something like this:

```
MATCH (ca:Category)<-[:PARENT*0..3]-(child)<-[:RELATES_TO]-()<-[:VOTED]-(visitor)
WHERE ca.name = 'Category A'
WITH distinct visitor
MATCH (cb:Category)<-[:RELATES_TO]-()<-[:VOTED]-(visitor)
USING INDEX cb:Category(name)
WHERE cb.name = 'Category B'
RETURN count(distinct(visitor)) as Cat_A_and_B_lovers
```

Your original query had one visitor repetition per category and vote so probably a lot of duplicates, for each of them the second match is executed.

How many visitors do you have per category-tree A ?
You might also flip the two around, i.e. first do 'B' then 'A'.

```
MATCH (cb:Category)<-[:RELATES_TO]-()<-[:VOTED]-(visitor)
WHERE cb.name = 'Category B'
WITH distinct visitor
MATCH (ca:Category)<-[:PARENT*0..3]-(child)<-[:RELATES_TO]-()<-[:VOTED]-(visitor)
USING INDEX ca:Category(name)
WHERE ca.name = 'Category A'
RETURN count(distinct(visitor)) as Cat_A_and_B_lovers
```

Also for counting it is only costly and not beneficial to count properties (visitor.id) when the nodes themselves represent the same concept.

Comment: Thank you Michael. Following your suggestions I am able to improve the runtime of my queries significantly. Still I am nowhere near my goal, which is getting the execution time below one second for each of these queries. Is this goal at all feasible with my amount of data?